# how to extract particular lines from the list?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list and wanted to extract a particular line from the list. Below is my list

[image]

I wanted to extract 'src link' from the above list

example:

(src="https://r-cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/244245064.webp?k=8699eb2006da453ae8fe257eee2dcc242e70667ef29845ed85f70dbb9f61726a&o="). My final aim is to extract only the link. I have 20 records in the list. Hence, the need to extract 20 links from the same

My code (I stored the list in 'aas')

`````
links = []

for i in aas:

    link = re.search('CONCLUSION: (.*?)([A-Z]{2,})', i).group(1)
    links.append(link)

````

I am getting an error: "expected string or bytes-like object"

Any suggestions?
`````

Comment: if you `print(type(i))` in your loop does it output `<class 'str'>` for all `i`s in your `aas` list?

Comment: @Phillyclause89 not it is not

Comment: What is the type of each item? Do this: `print(type(my_list[0]))` (`my_list` being the name of your list, whatever it is...).

Comment: @Phillyclause89 actually, I scraped the website using beautifulsoup. Type(i) is <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `for img in aas: print(img.attrs["src"])`

Comment: @GordonAitchJay type is <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>

Comment: Thanks @GordonAitchJay It's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Beautiful Soup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes), you can access a tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary, like so:

```py
for img in img_list:
    print(img["src"])
```